# Protocol buffers testing C++: expect/tcl/tk?

Tags: c++, automated-tests, expect, protocol-buffers

I have several modules that listen on determinate port to communicate with each other using UDP with protocol buffers (C++).
I need to automatize tests for each one of them.
Which is the best strategy to do the testing?

I mean I could write a C++ program that emulates each component using determined commands, for example in xml:

```
<commands>
  <send cmd="blahblah" from="module1" to="module2">
  <expect cmd="ack" from="module2" to="module1">
</commands>
```

but I was told that Expect/Tcl/Tk could be used. After some research, I think serialized protobuf's commands can't be done with static text, besides from what I have investigated, Expect works with output stream, and to test those components I need something that works with TCP/UDP sockets. Correct me if I am wrong. So is there some other tool to achieve this behavior (I mean sockets)?

I have no experience either with protobuf nor with expect. I would like to hear some opinions, maybe use some other tools to perform this type of testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect is not really suitable for binary data, so I wouldn't use it for protocol buffers messages.

I would recommend writing a small C++ (or any other language) program that takes a command to send and and an response to expect, like you suggested. You can use the [protocol buffers text format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873924/what-does-the-protobuf-text-format-look-like) to represent your data, so you do not have to write manual XML -> protobuf conversion for each message.