# What is the type of below mention data?

Tags: json, grpc, ietf-netmod-yang

I am receiving below mention data type as a result of service call. I need to parse this data, It doesn't seems like JSON or YANG, wondering what it is?

```
update {
  timestamp: 1513187126024174850
  prefix {
    elem {
      name: "interfaces"
    }
    elem {
      name: "interface"
      key {
        key: "name"
        value: "interface-0/0/0"
      }
   }

  }
```

Comment: You should add context here. What exactly did you do to end up with this text?  What do you mean by "service call"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like "text format" Protocol Buffers. The format is used with proto2 for human-readable display. In proto3 JSON is preferred, although text format is still available. The `protoc` tool is able to convert between text and binary protobuf.

I'm not aware of a formal definition of the syntax, but it is fairly simplistic. There's some examples on this other question: [What does the protobuf text format look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873924/what-does-the-protobuf-text-format-look-like)

Comment: Hi Eric, This is output from gNMI protoc3. Looks to me some sort of tree data.