# Can you directly load contents from a file into a protobuff?

Tags: python, string, parsing, protocol-buffers

I am reading the documentation and cannot seem to find anything explicit.

Let's say that I have a protobuf definition `MyObject.pb`.
I create an object of type `MyObject` and set each of its fields to some meaningful value. And assume all the values are proto primitives (int, floats, strings...).

Say that I store these values as a representing string that follows the same syntax as the definition.

e.g if MyObject.pb looks like:

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;
}
```

And the associated saved file looks like:

```
message Person {
  required string name = aStringName;
  required int32 id = 100;
  optional string email = ex@mple.com;
}
```

Is there a way to automatically initialize the protobuffer by giving the constructor the path to the representing string as an argument? or do you have to do the parsing manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it doesn't use exactly the same syntax as the definition, you can use the [`google.protobuf.text_format` module](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.text_format-module) to parse a more human-readable representation of a message. Specifically, the `Merge` method parses such a string into a protocol buffer, and the `MessageToString` method turns a protocol buffer into a string.

For your example message, the text representation would look like this:

```
name: "aStringName"
id: 100
email "ex@mple.com"
```

It can also handle nested messages. ([See this other answer for more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873924/what-does-the-protobuf-text-format-look-like/18877167#18877167))