# How to create model_config file for TFX Serving?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tfx

I have a bunch of custom defined model instances inheriting from  `tf.keras.layers.Layer` that I save. I would like to serve them with TFX Serving, which requires me to have a `model_config` file.

I am wondering how to create this according to the book. Right now I have the following code which I believe is more about my own bricolage than what I am supposed to do...

```
model_server_config = model_server_config_pb2.ModelServerConfig()

    #Create a config to add to the list of served models
    config_list = model_server_config_pb2.ModelConfigList()       
        
    for i in range(0,len(trainable_unit_name)): # add models one by one to the model config.    
        model_name  = name[i]
        base_path = "/models/{}".format(name[i])
        
        one_config = config_list.config.add()
        
        one_config.name           = model_name
        one_config.base_path      = base_path
        one_config.model_platform ="tensorflow"
        
    model_server_config.model_config_list.MergeFrom(config_list)
    with open(C.CONF_FILEPATH, 'w+') as f:        
        f.write("model_config_list {" + config_list.__str__() + "}") #manually wrap it around "model_config_list { .." because this is the required format by TFX Serving.
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete information regarding `Tensorflow Serving Configuration` is present in the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_config.

The answer to your question, how to create `model_config_file` for `Serving`, can be found in this [TF Serving Github Repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/config/model_server_config.proto).

For more information about PB Files, refer this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873924/what-does-the-protobuf-text-format-look-like).

Providing the `Github Code` below, just in case the above [Github Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/config/model_server_config.proto) doesn't work:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tensorflow.serving;
option cc_enable_arenas = true;

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "tensorflow_serving/config/logging_config.proto";
import "tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.proto";

// The type of model.    
enum ModelType {
  MODEL_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0 [deprecated = true];
  TENSORFLOW = 1 [deprecated = true];
  OTHER = 2 [deprecated = true];
};

// Common configuration for loading a model being served.
message ModelConfig {
  // Name of the model.
  string name = 1;
      
  repeated string alias = 9;

  string base_path = 2;

  // Type of model.
  // TODO(b/31336131): DEPRECATED. Please use 'model_platform' instead.
  ModelType model_type = 3 [deprecated = true];

  // Type of model (e.g. "tensorflow").
  //
  // (This cannot be changed once a model is in serving.)
  string model_platform = 4;

  reserved 5;

  // Version policy for the model indicating which version(s) of the model to
  // load and make available for serving simultaneously.
  // The default option is to serve only the latest version of the model.
  //
  // (This can be changed once a model is in serving.)
  FileSystemStoragePathSourceConfig.ServableVersionPolicy model_version_policy =
      7;

  // String labels to associate with versions of the model, allowing inference
  // queries to refer to versions by label instead of number. Multiple labels
  // can map to the same version, but not vice-versa.
  map<string, int64> version_labels = 8;

  // Configures logging requests and responses, to the model.
  //
  // (This can be changed once a model is in serving.)
  LoggingConfig logging_config = 6;
}

// Static list of models to be loaded for serving.
message ModelConfigList {
  repeated ModelConfig config = 1;
}

// ModelServer config.
message ModelServerConfig {
  // ModelServer takes either a static file-based model config list or an Any
  // proto representing custom model config that is fetched dynamically at
  // runtime (through network RPC, custom service, etc.).
  oneof config {
    ModelConfigList model_config_list = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any custom_model_config = 2;
  }
}
```