# Protobuf syntax with colons

Tags: syntax, protocol-buffers

Here are three examples of protobuf syntax.

1. [mscoco_label_map.pbtxt](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt)

   ```proto
   item {
     name: "/m/01g317"
     id: 1
     display_name: "person"
   }
   item {
     name: "/m/0199g"
     id: 2
     display_name: "bicycle"
   }
   ...
   ```
2. [en.wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats#Syntax_comparison_of_human-readable_formats)

   ```proto
   anotherfield {
     foo: 123
     bar: 456
   }
   anotherfield {
     foo: 222
     bar: 333
   }
   ```
3. [Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#simple)

   ```proto
   syntax = "proto3";

   message SearchRequest {
     string query = 1;
     int32 page_number = 2;
     int32 result_per_page = 3;
   }
   ```

Official (#3) example is obviously differs from #1 and #2. Did I miss a paragraph in official documentation which states that colon can be used instead of equal sign?

Official documentation describes a [JSON Mapping](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json), but there is not a single example that looks like #1 and #2. Also #1 and #2 is not a valid JSON either (missing quotes around keys, missing commas).

**Q**: where are #1 and #2 syntax came from?

Link to better (than official docs) syntax description is appreciated.

Comment: Your first two examples appear to be depicting *payloads*, where-as the third example is a *schema*; it is not surprising that these are entirely different, with the latter being the .proto syntax, and the former appearing to be ... well, I *would* say that they are depicting the opinionated JSON variant of protobuf, but honestly: that's not valid JSON, so it would surprise me hugely if that is actual data. Are you sure it isn't simply trying to depict the semantic structure, not the actual format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marc's Gravell response I was able to find out the answer.

#3 is a schema, *proto* syntax, think XSD (XML Schema Definition).

#1, #2 is a text dump of an actual data (payload), *textproto* syntax, **.pbtxt* file extension, think XML or JSON.

Related question: [What does the protobuf text format look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873924/what-does-the-protobuf-text-format-look-like)

Related links:

1. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format

   *C++ API for printing and parsing protocol messages in a human-readable, text-based format.*
2. https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/text_format.html

   *Python API*
3. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/proto3-spec

   *Protocol Buffers Version 3 Language Specification*
4. https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc#L288

   *Source code (C++) of text format ASCII representation parser.*
5. https://medium.com/@nathantnorth/protocol-buffers-text-format-14e0584f70a5

   *Protocol Buffers: Text Format* (2019-10-11, Nathan North)

   > There are a couple different ways to structure the data (instead of using brackets, you could use <>) but unfortunately nothing in this realm is terribly well documented so it’s more of a game of try it and see if it works.
6. https://gist.github.com/henridf/704c1c812f04a502c1c26f77a739090b

   *Encoding a protobuf with `protoc --encode`* (syntax example).

Clear syntax documentation of *protobuf text format* is still missing.